# Skitch drag/drop not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, drag-and-drop, skitch

I don't seem to be able to drag and drop from Skitch to a drag drop target.

The drop target doesn't seem to fire.
The typical green circle doesn't appear.

Thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/AAL86/5/

Comment: I am having the same issue with Gmail attachments and Skitch, for what its worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. Silly me.

The dragover event was messing with it for some reason, even though normal files worked fine.

Not quite sure why?

```
drop.addEventListener('dragover', function(e){
     //e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AAL86/6/